# ggplot2 error: Error in default + theme : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been getting the error *Error in default + theme : non-numeric argument to binary operator.*  I have been using R and teaching R for a long time but I can't find this problem.  I have included a reproducible example that fails this way below:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

brains <- as_tibble(brains)
brains <- brains[1:10, ]
brains
ggplot(brains, aes(x = BodyWt, y = BrainWt)) +
  geom_point()
```

The error occurs when executing the ggplot() statement.

My hardware is an HP Laptop 15-ef0xxx.  I am running Windows 10 Home version 2004.  I am running RStudio community edition "Water Lily" and R version R x64** 4.0.2.

I know this is a simple error and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please provide us with the data?  Without the actual dataset is is hard to debug the problem.

Comment: I was having this error because I used the %>% instead of the +. I read this thread and tried a bunch of options to correct it but it was a silly waste of time since it was just a syntax error.

Comment: I had this error because of another silly mistake. I was writing `theme_set(theme_linedraw)` instead of `theme_set(theme_linedraw())`. Logging this so that maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally solved this problem. On the github issue I had opened Hiroaki commented that "One possibility is that you might set a invalid default theme in your .Rprofile, but I'm not sure..." (see link to issue below).

I'm not sure if your R file is part of a project but mine is.
So I went back and deleted the theme_set() line in my R file, went in and double checked all my project options and selected the option "Disable .Rprofile execution on session start/resume" and "Quit child processes on exit".  And then I restarted the R session and now everything works.  Including on the default R editor console.
I'm not sure if all those steps are necessary but that seemed to do the trick for me! Hope it helps.

> I thought this was an RStudio issue but it seems it's possibly a ggplot2 > problem. I have verified using two different datasets that the same  >error comes up when I try using ggplot2 in RStudio or using the default R >console. I get the exact same error with code that's been working fine >but now suddenly won't. I have opened an issue on Github (ggplot2) with a >reprex.  Might be worth checking there: >https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4177
>
> I know this is not an answer per se but I don't have enough reputation >points to add a comment to the previous answer but I thought linking to >the issue on Github might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have numbers quoted somewhere and you are trying to perform mathematical operation on character values. Consider

```
  x <- c("5","6")
  y <- x/1

>   y <- x/1
Error in x/1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Now try converting x to numeric and perform the same operation.

```
y <- as.numeric(x)/1
>  y
[1] 5 6
```

So, you need to use as.numeric on your variable.
The following should resove this issue

```
ggplot(brains, aes(x = as.numeric(BodyWt), y = as.numeric(BrainWt)))
```